# Configure Https blocking http wildfly 8.2 (i.e without using security-constraint in web.xml)

Tags: xml, wildfly, jboss6.x, wildfly-8

**Migrate Jboss6 to WildFly8.2**

Working on https keystone connection in wildlfy8.2. After configuring my application on standalone-full.xml conf using http://blog.eisele.net/2015/01/ssl-with-wildfly-8-and-undertow.html. I was able to access both http and https on my application i have to access https alone blocking http. After adding **security-constraint** inside web.xml i was able to redirect to https. But i don't want to include anything in web.xml in my new version it affects my old jboss users.

In a situation there are people who use jboss6 application without SSL keystore configuration and people using same applications in Https .
Older version of jboss allows both http and https to be configured in server.xml itself. In wildfly we have to edit application war file instead of server config files.

Note : I got this link having same issue got resolved in  https://developer.jboss.org/thread/253008?_sscc=t. made the changes as instructed. But it doesn't work, we are using standalone-full.xml instead of standalone.xml.

After making changes i am getting web-service port error :

```
jboss.deployment.subunit."XXX.ear"."XXXEJB3.jar".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment "XXXEJB3.jar" of deployment "XXX.ear"
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS017350: Could not find the port number listening for protocol HTTP/1.1
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.WebServerService.getPort(WebServerService.java:67)
at org.jboss.as.webservices.config.WebServerInfoImpl.getPort(WebServerInfoImpl.java:36)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Http bloacking and Https enabling make changes to standalone-full.xml(i.e for custom server) or standalone.xml as follows

1: In messaging - hornetq-server subsystem connectors change http to https

```
<http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="https">
<http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" socket-binding="https">
```

2: In undertow subsystem change

```
   <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http"/>
```

to

```
<https-listener name="default-ssl" socket-binding="https" security-realm="UndertowRealm"/>
```

**Note**: https-listener name **default-ssl** use this name in messaging subsystem http-acceptor and remoting subsystem http-connector

3: Give messaging - hornetq-server subsystem http-acceptor and remoting subsystem http-connector's connector-ref as https-listener name

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging:2.0">....
<http-acceptor http-listener="default-ssl" name="http-acceptor"/>
<http-acceptor http-listener="default-ssl" name="http-acceptor-throughput">...</subsystem>

<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:remoting:2.0">....
<http-connector name="http-remoting-connector" connector-ref="default-ssl" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>....</subsystem>
```

For error : Added modify-wsdl-address to **true** and wsdl-port to **80** than https worked blocking http.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:1.2">
        <modify-wsdl-address>true</modify-wsdl-address>
        <wsdl-host>${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}</wsdl-host>
        <wsdl-port>80</wsdl-port>
        <endpoint-config name="Standard-Endpoint-Config"/>
        <endpoint-config name="Recording-Endpoint-Config">
            <pre-handler-chain name="recording-handlers" protocol-bindings="##SOAP11_HTTP ##SOAP11_HTTP_MTOM ##SOAP12_HTTP ##SOAP12_HTTP_MTOM">
                <handler name="RecordingHandler" class="org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.RecordingServerHandler"/>
            </pre-handler-chain>
        </endpoint-config>
        <client-config name="Standard-Client-Config"/>
    </subsystem>
```